# Build and generate script for SSDT project using command line tools

Tags: sql-server, msbuild, sql-server-data-tools, sqlpackage

I am trying to achieve following workflow using command line:

1. Build the project using specific variables overriding via command line (for example I have $(buildVersion) variable in publish config that has some value. I would like to override the $(buildVersion) by entered value command line. The output of this step is dacpac file
2. Generate the publish script based on the generated dacpac file and the actual database

I tried to use both SqlPackage.exe and MSBuild.exe tools. However I can't get desired effect as:

- I can't find the way how to build project with SqlPackage
- I can't find the way how to pass variables to MSBuild

What I can now:

- I can build the project using MSBuild
- I can generate the publish script with SqlPackage

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The stuff in a publish profile for a database project doesn't affect the *build* step where the `dacpac` is created, after all you can have as many publish profiles as you like for a single project.

When generating the publish script with `sqlpackage.exe`, you can pass variables like

`sqlpackage.exe /action:script /sourcefile:mydacpac.dacpac /v:BuildNumber=xyz`

Comment: Ohh, I didn't think about the thing that variables values are not stored in the dacpac ... thanks